# How to calculate percentage from a Tuple or a Model in c#

Tags: c#, sql

From tables in SQL, I ran some query to get the following data:

```
Table A:
    Month   total
    1        81
    2        45
    3        38
    4        73
    5        69

Table B:
   Month    total
    1        103
    2        85
    3        56
    4        106
    5        98
```

Table A shows the count with certain criteria, and Table B shows the total count. What I need to do is get the percentage of the counts in Table A. So, for the above example, I should get the following table.

```
Table Result:
       Month    total
        1        78.64
        2        52.94
        3        67.8
        4        68.88
        5        70.40
```

It's really easy to do using statistical tools like R. I need to do this in either SQL or C#.

One way I'm doing this using c# is by using Tuple. For example,

```
Tuple<double, double>[] risks = 
        {
            new Tuple<double, double>(1, 81),
            new Tuple<double, double>(2, 45),
            new Tuple<double, double>(3, 38),
            new Tuple<double, double>(4, 73),
            new Tuple<double, double>(5, 69)
        };

        Tuple<double, double>[] prescribers = 
        {
            new Tuple<double, double>(1, 103),
            new Tuple<double, double>(2, 85),
            new Tuple<double, double>(3, 56),
            new Tuple<double, double>(4, 106),
            new Tuple<double, double>(5, 98)
        };

        for(var i = 0; i< risks.Length; i++){


            Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(risks[i].Item2 * 100/prescribers[i].Item2, 2));

        }
```

It gives me the correct answer, but I don't think it's the most efficient way to handle this problem. Is there a better way to do this? It'd be better if I can combine these two tables and create a new column called percentage.

The query I ran on the SQL is the following:

For Table A:

```
with risk as (select id from ScreeningTools where coalesce(ort,dast, comm, dire, pduq, pmq) is not null or other <> '') 
select DATEPART(month, A.createdOn) as Month, count(distinct(A.prescriberId)) as total from Auths A 
inner join risk R
on R.id = A.id
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, A.createdOn) = DATEPART(YEAR, '2017')
GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH, A.createdOn);
```

For Table B:

```
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, A.createdOn) as Month, COUNT(DISTINCT(A.prescriberId)) as total
FROM Auths A
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, A.createdOn) = DATEPART(YEAR, '2017')
GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH, A.createdOn);
```

I'm open to either way (SQL or C#). Right now, the dataset is very small so it's relatively fast. As time goes on, dataset will grow significantly.

Comment: You can do this very easy in a query.  Insert your Table A and Table B queries into two table variables, join on the month and select (A/B) as "Average from A inner join B on A.Month  = B.Month. Not sure what flavor of SQL you are using,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is SQL way, where you simply join the two results over Month, and calculate the percentage:

```
SELECT a.Month, a.Total, b.Total, a.Total * 100 / b.Total as [Percentage]
FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b on a.Month = b.Month
```

Second is to do client-side via LINQ.  You can use `Tuple` or plain class for representing data, but however you store it:

```
sourceA.Join(sourceB, 
    a => a.Month, 
    b => b.Month, 
    (a, b) => new { a.Month, TotalA = a.Total, TotalB = b.Total, Percentage = a.Total * 100 / b.Total}
```

Comment: Wow. That SQL statement was so simple. Not sure why I didn't think about it. I kept thinking like in R with dplyr package, and I kept getting error. It is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this.

```
select a.[month], CAST(CAST(a.total As float) / b.total * 100 As decimal(8, 2)) per
--into #Tempp
from Table_1 a
join Table_2 b on a.[month]=b.[month]

--select * from #Tempp
```